# Can't use function return value in write context in my CI_Controller

Tags: php

```
    <?php
    class Cart extends CI_Controller{

   public $paypal_data = '';
   public $tax;
   public $shipping;
   public $total =0;
   public $grand_total;

   //cart index
   public function index(){
    //load view
    $data('main_content') = 'cart';
    $this->load->view('layouts/main', $data);
   }//end function

   //add to Cart
   public function add(){
    //item data in a array construct
    $data = array('id'=> $this->input->post('item_number'), 'qty'=>   $this->input->post('qty'), 'price'=> $this->input->post('price'), 'name'=>  $this->input->post('title'));//end statement

   }//end function

}//end class cart
```

The above code causes error as follows:"Fatal error: Cant' use function return value in write context". I looked and searched many time at the above code but just can not seem to find the error. I would greatly appreciate it if someone can help.

Comment: Probably this line: `$data('main_content') = 'cart'`. What's `$data`? If it's an array, you don't want to use parentheses...

Comment: That should probably be `$data['main_content']`. Parentheses are for calling functions, square brackets are for indexing arrays. But you have no `$data` array.

Comment: Maybe it should be `$this->data['main_content']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
$data('main_content') = 'cart';
```

Using parentheses means you're calling a function, but you can't assign to a function call. You probably meant to assign to an array index, but you have no `$data` array. I see you've created `$data` in the `add()` function, but that variable is local to that function. They probably both should be class properties, so they should be `$this->data`. And in `index()` you need to use square brackets.

```
   public function index(){
    //load view
    $this->data['main_content'] = 'cart';
    $this->load->view('layouts/main', $this->data);
   }//end function

   //add to Cart
   public function add(){
    //item data in a array construct
    $this->data = array('id'=> $this->input->post('item_number'), 'qty'=>   $this->input->post('qty'), 'price'=> $this->input->post('price'), 'name'=>  $this->input->post('title'));//end statement

   }//end function
```

Comment: I have tested it with the print_r($data); and you are indeed correct. Thank You very much.

Comment: There is no need to use class properties, at least not in the index-function as the OP just sending data to the view. This is normally limited to be used within the controller method in CI.

Comment: @jtheman I wasn't sure. It looked to me like it wanted to use the same array that's being updated in `add()`. I'm not familiar with CI.

Comment: @Barmar I understand. But in CI the default way of sending data to a view is setting a simple data array in the specific controller method and then passing the array as the second argument to the `load->view()` method. Of course your answer is fully working as well.

Answer (score 0):

May error in this line

```
$data = array();
$data['main_content'] = 'cart';
```